# Excel file linked to Access; Access linked to Power Query; Excel file pop up when refreshin PowerQuery

Tags: excel, ms-access, powerquery

I have the following situation:

1- I have one Excel File linked to my Access database called "Input"
I use this file to create a query that allows to extract only the information from the references in the "Input" file.

2- After creating the query (merge) I get this extraction with the Power Query function from my "Main" table i use to work.
I do this because in the Access i have tables with +1M rows and PowerQuery cannot handle them.

When i refresh my linked PowerQuery tables that comes from "Input+merged info" the "Input" Excel would open.
This happens with every single Excel file i link to the Access and get them with PowerQuery later on.
It seems that to "refresh" the information it is going all the way down to the source of the information and opening it to update it.

There is an option to solve this and it is importing the Excel Files - but that generates an extra work that would complicate everything as Access size would be +2GB.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thank you!!

Comment: Is there any way to separate old data into a new table that doesn't need to be queried? That way you could keep the data for documentation purposes but it wouldn't need to be queried every time?

Comment: Are there any users using the access DB while you perform the refresh or a network process that may be blocking the excel file?

Comment: @TiannaWrona the data is a list of references with information related to the parts (quantites and prices) so all the information changes all the time.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz i'm the only user. The Access DB is local for me, so no one is using the db but me.

Comment: This has happened to me, and what I found was that a process was accessing the files while the query was taking place

Comment: @RicardoDiaz please can you clarify what you mean with "a process". Do you remember what type of process? Is this the type of processes I could check using the task manager?

Comment: I don't remember the details sorry. Was long ago.